# "Contracts on Rococo" down?

Tags: parachain, smart-contract, rococo

gm, tried setting up my boilerplate https://inkathon.xyz with contracts on rococo as suggested in the docs: https://use.ink/testnet.

unfortunately, neither i'm able to receive funds from the faucet (despite getting a success answer from the bot). nor i receive funds sent via XCM from the relay chain.

then i just saw the last block was 17hr ago....

https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-contracts-rpc.polkadot.io#/explorer

Comment: Indeed, the team is now aware and working on it. Will post a comment shortly once its up again.

Answer (score 1):

Contracts is up and running again.